# Run adiitional cleanup function on test failure (when Assertion Fails)

Tags: c#, unit-testing, selenium, nunit, assert

I currently have a test suite using Nunit and C# with Selenium WebDriver using assertions, is there a way to have a function run only if the assertion fails. Normally this will continue to the teardown and then proceed to the next test, however I need to reset certain parameters on the test if the previous test fails. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: You could try http://programmers.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic when your questions are not about a specific piece of code.

Comment: You could check in the teardown if the test status is failed via `TestContext.CurrentContext.Result.Status` and run whatever methods you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could extend the TestActionAttribute to handle this. In the `AfterTest()` override, you can check `TestContext.CurrentContext.Result.Status == TestStatus.Failed` and handle appropriately. E.g.,

```
public class ClassTest
{
    [Test]
    [OnFailure] // << your custom attribute here
    public void MyTest()
    {
        Assert.Fail("test failed");
    }
}

[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method)]
public class OnFailureAttribute : TestActionAttribute
{
    public override void AfterTest(TestDetails testDetails)
    {
        if(TestContext.CurrentContext.Result.Status == TestStatus.Failed)
        {
            // TODO: your error handling
            Console.WriteLine(testDetails.FullName + " failed");
        }
    }
}
```